# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name can't be converted

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I designed a database with a column `user_id`. Now in my form page after login when I click an insert button I need fill `user_id` with the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

But it show me an error. I convert to int.parse or string or I just used `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` still error. Can anyone help me?

For example

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

I should add that my `user_id` column is of the data type `int` in SQL Server 2008.

It says me it is `IConvertible` and can't be converted at all .. not to `string` or `int`.

Then how can I fill `user_id` in db after login?

Comment: The `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is your user name - e.g. `Susan` - how do you want to convert this to an `int` ???

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for a few reasons:

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("user_id".httpcontext.current.user.identity");
```

1. It won't compile - **NOTE:** please included compilable code in examples in the future.
2. `Identity` here is an `IIdentity`. This isn't going to convert to an `int`.
3. The user ID is *not stored*, *nor available*, off of the `IPrincipal`.

You need to recover the user ID by making a round-trip to the database. The only thing available to you is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

---

Now, what I've done in the past is add a method to my `UserProfile` model, you know, the one that's used by the provider you're leveraging to actually create a user record when this is called:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
    new
    {
        // additional profile fields are passed as an anonymous type
        CustomField1 = model.CustomField1
    });
```

and here is the `UserProfile` method:

```
public static int? PrincipalUserId(IPrincipal user)
{
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var key = string.Format("userid_{0}", user.Identity.Name);

    int userId;
    if (!SharedCacheManager.TryGetValue<int>(key, out userId))
    {
        using (UsersContext udb = new UsersContext())
        {
            userId = udb.UserProfiles
                .Where(up => up.UserName == user.Identity.Name)
                .First().UserId;
        }

        SharedCacheManager.SetValue<int>(key, userId);
    }

    return userId;
}
```

and here is the `SharedCacheManager`:

```
public static class SharedCacheManager
{
    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T result)
    {
        var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

        object o = cache[key];
        if (o == null)
        {
            result = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() != typeof(T))
        {
            result = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        result = (T)o;
        return true;
    }

    public static void SetValue<T>(string key, T val)
    {
        var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
        cache[key] = val;
    }
}
```

Now, all of this code isn't going to just **drop** into your solution. But it can be very easily modified.